# The twilio module in Parse Cloud is missing latest APIs

Tags: parse-platform, twilio, parse-cloud-code

Based on the API documentation on twilio.com, `twilio.availablePhoneNumbers('COUNTRY_CODE').mobile.get()` should exist. I should be able to call something like this below:

```
twilio.availablePhoneNumbers('US').mobile.get({
    smsEnabled: true
}).then(function(searchResults) {
    ....
});
```

But when I used twilio module provided inside Parse cloud code, `twilio.availablePhoneNumbers('COUNTRY_CODE').local` and `twilio.availablePhoneNumbers('COUNTRY_CODE').tollFree` are available.

Am I wrong?

I need to programmatically acquire a phone number in the cloud code. If twilio on Parse cloud code is limited, how can I use the latest twilio APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The Twilio module on Parse is indeed outdated. I am currently working with their team to get an updated version available for developers like yourself.

In the meantime, you could use a normal HTTP request on Parse without the Twilio module to make calls like the one you are after. Something like this might work for now:

```
var accountSid = 'AC123...'; // your account SID
var authToken = 'xyzabc...'; // your auth token
var countryCode = 'US'; // the country code you want to search within

var url = 'https://';
url += accountSid + ':' + authToken + '@'; // add auth to URL
url += 'api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/';
url += accountSid;
url += '/AvailablePhoneNumbers/';
url += countryCode;
url += '/Mobile.json';

Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
  url: url,
}).then(function(httpResponse) {
  // success
  console.log(httpResponse.text);
  // httpResponse.data is the parsed JSON response
},function(httpResponse) {
  // error
  console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
});
```

You might want to check out the documentation for Parse's `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest`. It's available here: https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-advanced

Comment: Just a heads up to you, looks like Parse is backtracking on their modules idea : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1024338347618594/

Comment: @lightice11 That makes sense. Managing 3rd party modules should not be a focus for Parse.